How can I allow an anonymous user to upload a file in [2sxc]
I am running Mobius Forms Builder v6, on 2sxc 17.9.0 in dnn 9.11.2
I have a simple form with some text fields and a file upload control.
I have activated the features:

Public Upload of Files
SaveInAdam API

I got the following error: "An unexpected error occured while sending. Please try again. If it fails again, please send it by E-Mail."
No errors in the eventlog.
Logged in as a host, the file upload works as expected.
I tried setting the permissions in the dnn file manager for the adam directory, but that did not help

Are you sure it's not a firewall rule that's preventing this? Because this is a very standard use case for Mobius, so it should just work out of the box.

Responding a bit late, I assume that when it is a firewall case, the form would also not work for a host user. It is a local dev site
